# IE8 problem with multilingual website

Tags: asp.net, browser, internet-explorer-8

Hi i have develop and deploy one multilingual (english uk and swedish) website at India in following server

> Intel® Xeon® Processor, 2.00+ GHz 4 GB
>   RAM 350+ GB HDD (usable hard disk
>   space) Windows Server 2008 standard
>   edition Oracle 10g Standard Edition

When user at sweden is accessing website from sweden they are facing following problem

> Culture 'sv' is a neutral culture. It
>   cannot be used in formatting and
>   parsing and therefore cannot be set as
>   the thread's current culture

One point i had observed during analysis is that the language of their browser is **Svenska[sv]** but i never found such language at my browser in India here two language are available for sweden Swedish Finland(sv-FI) and Swedish(sv-SE).

Can any one help me to find out cause of problem? How should i proceed further? I have never seen **Svenska[sv]**  in my browser language option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Swedish [sv]` is certainly listed as an available generic langauge in my browsers. It's normal to specify both a specific language and a generic one as fallback, eg. `en-gb,en`. In any case the user may add any arbitrary language name like `potato-PANTS` to the `Accept-Language` header so you should certainly not be blindly setting CurrentCulture from it on the server side.

Instead, check whether it matches any known-supported language values for your site, and maps those to known-good cultures. So for your example, check if any `sv` language is listed in the header and use `sv-SE` if so, otherwise default to `en-GB`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the CurrentUICulture of current thread instead of CurrentCulture.